# How does return by reference work in C++ classes?

Tags: c++, class, reference, return-by-reference

In `C++`, if i type:

```
int x=5;
int &y=x;
```

then `y` will act as an alias for the memory location where original `x` is stored and this can be proven/tested by printing the memory location of both, `x` and `y`

the output of a similar program is below:

```
x is at location: 0x23fe14
y is at location: 0x23fe14
```

But what about **classes**?

when a member function is declared with **return type** as a reference and the function uses the `this` pointer, what is the function actually returning?

for example:

```
#include <iostream>
class simple
{
    int data;
public:
    // ctor
    simple():
        data(0)
        {}

    // getter function
    int& getter_data()
    {   return this->data;    }

    // modifier functions
    simple& add(int x=5)
    {   this->data += x;
        return *this;
    }
    simple& sub(int x=5)
    {   this->data -= x;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{   simple obj;
    obj.add().sub(4);  ////////// how & why is it working? /////////
    std::cout<<obj.getter_data();
    getchar();
}
```

why is it possible to execute the command in highlighted line?

what kind of data is `obj.add()` returning to the `sub()`?

Comment: It's a reference to the object you called `add` on. It's not different from built-in types at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your member-function returns `simple&` initialized with `*this` (`*this` being an instance of `simple`) the semantics are the same as your own "reference example"; a *reference*  is initialized with an *instance* of that type.

You are initializing the returned reference with the object itself.

---

The below snippets are semantically equivalent:

```
obj.add ().sub (4);
```

```
simple& ref = obj.add ();

ref.sub (4); // `ref` is really `obj`,
             // the address of `ref` and `obj` are the same
```

Comment: so, talking in terms of addresses, what you trying to say is: `obj.add();` returns an alias object for the same address, where `obj` is originally stored. did i get it right?

Comment: @zibs.shirsh yes, that's one way to describe what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

> what kind of data is obj.add() returning to the sub()?

`obj.add()` is returning a reference to the `obj` instance.

The text "returning to the `sub()`" is not making sense at all.

However, in your case, the reference to your object is very similar to a plain pointer to your object, and often it is a good metapher.